# Take a list in list according to json in recyclerview

Tags: android, json, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I am building an app that uses dynamic `json` and data is fetched from the server. The json data also contains nested `json array`.

This data needs to be presented in `RecyclerView`. I have managed to display some part of data in `RecyclerView`.

I showed parent arrays data , but how to show object array's data in to view that also have array in it.
My json like

```
[

    {"_id":"5a8fa892f399c80f95ac0c81",

    object: "1", 

    type:"type-1",

    question : "Question lorem ipsum ?"

    answer : [  
{  
    "id":"A",
    "is_correct":"false",
    "_id":"5a8fa892f399c80f95ac0c85",
    "matching_id":[  
        ""
    ],
    "text":"text option 1"
},
{  
    "id":"B",
    "is_correct":"true",
    "_id":"5a8fa892f399c80f95ac0c84",
    "matching_id":[  
        ""
    ],
    "text":"text option 2"
},
{  
    "id":"C",
    "is_correct":"false",
    "_id":"5a8fa892f399c80f95ac0c83",
    "matching_id":[  
        ""
    ],
    "text":"text option 3"
  }
 ]
 },

   {"_id":"5a8fa892f399c8081",

    object: "2", 

    type:"type-2",

    question : "Question lorem ipsum 2?"

    answer : [  
{  
    "id":"A",
    "is_correct":"false",
    "_id":"5a8fa892f399c80f95ac0c85",
    "matching_id":[  
        ""
    ],
    "text":"text option 1a"
},
{  
    "id":"B",
    "is_correct":"true",
    "_id":"5a8fa892f399c80f95ac0c84",
    "matching_id":[  
        ""
    ],
    "text":"text option 2a"
},
{  
    "id":"C",
    "is_correct":"false",
    "_id":"5a8fa892f399c80f95ac0c83",
    "matching_id":[  
        ""
    ],
    "text":"text option 3a"
  }
 ]
 }    
]
```

I have succeeded in to show the question part but how to the answer's part in `Recyclerview's` view . Every question have answers option, so in every view i have to show answers option , taking from this json 
into `recycelrview`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code is not exactly what you want to do ... so copy paste will not work well.
Look at the logic

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //ypu should do this:
    //you adapter constructor has a JSONArray in paramater





    //List<QuestionObjects> questionObjects = new ArrayList<>();

    //List<AnswerObjects> answersObjects = new ArrayList<>();



    try {
        String jsonquest = response.body().string();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: jsonQuest: " + jsonquest);
        JSONArray questionwithresponses = new JSONArray(jsonquest);




        /*for (int i = 0; i < question.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject e = question.getJSONObject(i);

            newQuestionObject._id = e.getString("_id");
            newQuestionObject.question = e.getString("question");
            newQuestionObject.type = e.getString("type");

            JSONArray answers =e.getJSONArray("answers");

            for (int j = 0 ; j <answers.length(); j++) {

                JSONObject a = answers.getJSONObject(j);

                Answers newAnswers = new Answers();

                newAnswers.id = a.getString("id");

                newAnswers.isCorrect = a.getString("is_correct");

                newAnswers.idAnswer = a.getString("_id");

                newAnswers.text = a.getString("text");

                answersObjects.add(newAnswers);

            }

            newQuestionObject.answers = answersObjects;*/
        mExamView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

  mAdapter = new QuestionAdapter(ExamActivity.this,questionwithresponses);

        mExamView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mExamView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mExamView.setLayoutManager(newLinearLayoutManager(ExamActivity.this));
        submitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.test_submit_btn);
        mExamView.setDuplicateParentStateEnabled(true);


        }



    }
    catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();
   Toast.makeText(ExamActivity.this, "error in data",   

   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    }


}
```

for the adapter

public class adapter {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub




  public class QuestionAdapter extends

 RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

 public static final String TAG = QuestionAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

 private Context context;

 private LayoutInflater inflater;
 JSONArray questionwithresponses;
 QuestionObjects current;
 private int currentPos=0;
 int total_types;

 //ArrayList<Answers>AnswerData;
Answers answer;
int getTotal_types;


 // Create constructor to initialize context and data sent from 

 ExamActivity

 //don't use this constructor...

 public QuestionAdapter(Context context, List<QuestionObjects> data, 

 ArrayList<Answers> AnswerData){

    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data = data;
    this.AnswerData= AnswerData;

   }
//use this one
public QuestionAdapter(Context context, JSONArray quesRep){
    this.context = context;

    this.questionwithresponses=quesRep;

}
public static class TextTypeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView txtTpe;
    CardView cardView;

    public TextTypeViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);

    }
}


 //    Inflate the layout when viewholder created

@Override

public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int 

viewType){
//        Context context =parent.getContext();
 //
 //        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.match_the_following_questions, 
  parent, false);
    MyHolder holder = new MyHolder(view);
    return holder;

}

 //    Bind data

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int  

currentPos ) {

//        Get current position of item i recycler view to bind data and  

 assign values from list

    //if some raisons you have to use object create by  

 //yourself(QuestionObjects,Answers) you can rebuild them here
    //otherwise you can use JSONObject directly
    JSONObjet current=questionwithresponses.get(currentPos);


    MyHolder myHolder = (MyHolder) holder;


    myHolder.questionU.setText(current.getString("question"));
    myHolder.qNumber.setText(current.getString(""));

    JSONArray answer=object.getJSONOArray("answer")
            //to liste answers
            for(int i=0;i<answers.lenght();i++)
            {
            JSONObject answer=answers.getJSONObject(i);
             //you can get all you need about anwers here
            //exemple

             myHolder.op1.setText(answer.getString("text"));//or whatever    

  you want
            }





    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: "+current +"    myHolder"  


   +current.question_number);
 }



@Override
public long getItemId(int currentPos){
    return currentPos;

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

 return (position ==questionwithresponses .lenght() ?          

 R.layout.activity_exam : R.id.test_submit_btn) ;

}

//    return total item from List
@Override

public int getItemCount() {
    return questionwithresponses .lenght();
}

class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView questionU;
    TextView qNumber;
    TextView op1, op2, op3, op4;

  //        create constructor to get widget reference

    public MyHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);

        questionU = itemView.findViewById(R.id.question);
        qNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.questionnumber);

        op1= itemView.findViewById(R.id.option1);
        op2 =itemView.findViewById(R.id.option2);
        op3 =itemView.findViewById(R.id.option3);
        op4 =itemView.findViewById(R.id.option4);
    }
}

}


}

}
```

Comment: I have already done this step, ahead this i want to show this for loop's data into every view of recyclerview

Comment: Here is the link to the  [code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jtMHuus2tpq7mRLrL-3kpSc8edg1qeeZ)

Comment: i can't get your code couse don't have autorisation. Just copie the code inside your adapter and pass it as code by editing your question.

Comment: check this i have added permission  [Link] (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jtMHuus2tpq7mRLrL-3kpSc8edg1qeeZ?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I have taken look of you json and having seen that I can say you should have used Expandable recycler view not recyclerview here.

Have look here
https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view

Comment: But i want show data in one view(not want to add expandable view)